# Understanding struct.pack in python 2.7 and 3.5+

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, struct

I am attempting to understand; and resolve, why the following happens:

```
$ python
>>> import struct
>>> list(struct.pack('hh', *(50,50)))
['2', '\x00', '2', '\x00']
>>> exit()
$ python3
>>> import struct
>>> list(struct.pack('hh', *(50, 50)))
[50, 0, 50, 0]
```

I understand that `hh` stands for 2 shorts.  I understand that `struct.pack` is converting the two integers (shorts) to a `c style struct`.  But why does the output in 2.7 differ so much from 3.5?

Unfortunately I am stuck with `python 2.7` for right now on this project and I need the output to be similar to one from `python 3.5`

In response to comment from Some Programmer Dude

```
$ python
>>> import struct
>>> a = list(struct.pack('hh', *(50, 50)))
>>> [int(_) for _ in a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Loop over the list and create a list converting all characters to integers? List comprehension would work well for that.

Comment: These outputs are absolutely the same. `ord('2') == 50`, `ord('\x00') == 0`, this is just a matter of representation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude see edit

Comment: If you'd printed the return value *without* `list()` you'd have noticed that the return value is `'2\x002\x00'` vs `b'2\x002\x00'`; and then you'd have asked about the difference between `list('abc')` in python 2 and `list(b'abc')` in Python 3.

Comment: @ForceBru they're _not_ the same. One is a list of of `str` objects, the other is a list of `int` objects, obtained by iterating on a `bytes` object.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I know about `str` and `bytes`, but this is just a notation. The meaning is the same, however.

Comment: @ForceBru I know you know :) the question is "why is the result of `pack` different between the 2 versions ?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in python 2, `struct.pack('hh', *(50,50))` returns a `str` object.

This has changed in python 3, where it returns a `bytes` object (difference between binary and string is a very important difference between both versions, even if `bytes` exists in python 2, it is the same as `str`).

To emulate this behaviour in python 2, you could get ASCII code of the characters by appling `ord` to each char of the result:

```
map(ord,struct.pack('hh', *(50,50)))
```

Comment: I wish to be like you one day Sir!