# How to remove the error "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes"

Tags: python

I tried the [GitHub code](https://github.com/TestStudio/usbmuxd/blob/master/python-client/usbmux.py) to make a USB connection with an iOS device and Python on a PC.

The above code was created in Python2, so I ran `2to3 -w usbmux.py` to convert it to Python3 code.

The Python3 code is as follows.

```
import socket, struct, select, sys

try:
    import plistlib
    haveplist = True
except:
    haveplist = False

class MuxError(Exception):
    pass

class MuxVersionError(MuxError):
    pass

class SafeStreamSocket:
    def __init__(self, address, family):
        self.sock = socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(address)
    def send(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < len(msg):
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise MuxError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent
    def recv(self, size):
        msg = ''
        while len(msg) < size:
            chunk = self.sock.recv(size-len(msg))
            if chunk == '':
                raise MuxError("socket connection broken")
            msg = msg + chunk
        return msg

class MuxDevice(object):
    def __init__(self, devid, usbprod, serial, location):
        self.devid = devid
        self.usbprod = usbprod
        self.serial = serial
        self.location = location
    def __str__(self):
        return "<MuxDevice: ID %d ProdID 0x%04x Serial '%s' Location 0x%x>"%(self.devid, self.usbprod, self.serial, self.location)

class BinaryProtocol(object):
    TYPE_RESULT = 1
    TYPE_CONNECT = 2
    TYPE_LISTEN = 3
    TYPE_DEVICE_ADD = 4
    TYPE_DEVICE_REMOVE = 5
    VERSION = 0
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self.connected = False

    def _pack(self, req, payload):
        if req == self.TYPE_CONNECT:
            return struct.pack("IH", payload['DeviceID'], payload['PortNumber']) + "\x00\x00"
        elif req == self.TYPE_LISTEN:
            return ""
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid outgoing request type %d"%req)

    def _unpack(self, resp, payload):
        if resp == self.TYPE_RESULT:
            return {'Number':struct.unpack("I", payload)[0]}
        elif resp == self.TYPE_DEVICE_ADD:
            devid, usbpid, serial, pad, location = struct.unpack("IH256sHI", payload)
            serial = serial.split("\0")[0]
            return {'DeviceID': devid, 'Properties': {'LocationID': location, 'SerialNumber': serial, 'ProductID': usbpid}}
        elif resp == self.TYPE_DEVICE_REMOVE:
            devid = struct.unpack("I", payload)[0]
            return {'DeviceID': devid}
        else:
            raise MuxError("Invalid incoming request type %d"%req)

    def sendpacket(self, req, tag, payload={}):
        payload = self._pack(req, payload)
        if self.connected:
            raise MuxError("Mux is connected, cannot issue control packets")
        length = 16 + len(payload)
        data = struct.pack("IIII", length, self.VERSION, req, tag) + payload
        self.socket.send(data)
    def getpacket(self):
        if self.connected:
            raise MuxError("Mux is connected, cannot issue control packets")
        dlen = self.socket.recv(4)
        dlen = struct.unpack("I", dlen)[0]
        body = self.socket.recv(dlen - 4)
        version, resp, tag = struct.unpack("III",body[:0xc])
        if version != self.VERSION:
            raise MuxVersionError("Version mismatch: expected %d, got %d"%(self.VERSION,version))
        payload = self._unpack(resp, body[0xc:])
        return (resp, tag, payload)

class PlistProtocol(BinaryProtocol):
    TYPE_RESULT = "Result"
    TYPE_CONNECT = "Connect"
    TYPE_LISTEN = "Listen"
    TYPE_DEVICE_ADD = "Attached"
    TYPE_DEVICE_REMOVE = "Detached" #???
    TYPE_PLIST = 8
    VERSION = 1
    def __init__(self, socket):
        if not haveplist:
            raise Exception("You need the plistlib module")
        BinaryProtocol.__init__(self, socket)

    def _pack(self, req, payload):
        return payload

    def _unpack(self, resp, payload):
        return payload

    def sendpacket(self, req, tag, payload={}):
        payload['ClientVersionString'] = 'usbmux.py by marcan'
        if isinstance(req, int):
            req = [self.TYPE_CONNECT, self.TYPE_LISTEN][req-2]
        payload['MessageType'] = req
        payload['ProgName'] = 'tcprelay'
        BinaryProtocol.sendpacket(self, self.TYPE_PLIST, tag, plistlib.writePlistToString(payload))
    def getpacket(self):
        resp, tag, payload = BinaryProtocol.getpacket(self)
        if resp != self.TYPE_PLIST:
            raise MuxError("Received non-plist type %d"%resp)
        payload = plistlib.readPlistFromString(payload)
        return payload['MessageType'], tag, payload

class MuxConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, socketpath, protoclass):
        self.socketpath = socketpath
        if sys.platform in ['win32', 'cygwin']:
            family = socket.AF_INET
            address = ('127.0.0.1', 27015)
        else:
            family = socket.AF_UNIX
            address = self.socketpath
        self.socket = SafeStreamSocket(address, family)
        self.proto = protoclass(self.socket)
        self.pkttag = 1
        self.devices = []

    def _getreply(self):
        while True:
            resp, tag, data = self.proto.getpacket()
            if resp == self.proto.TYPE_RESULT:
                return tag, data
            else:
                raise MuxError("Invalid packet type received: %d"%resp)
    def _processpacket(self):
        resp, tag, data = self.proto.getpacket()
        if resp == self.proto.TYPE_DEVICE_ADD:
            self.devices.append(MuxDevice(data['DeviceID'], data['Properties']['ProductID'], data['Properties']['SerialNumber'], data['Properties']['LocationID']))
        elif resp == self.proto.TYPE_DEVICE_REMOVE:
            for dev in self.devices:
                if dev.devid == data['DeviceID']:
                    self.devices.remove(dev)
        elif resp == self.proto.TYPE_RESULT:
            raise MuxError("Unexpected result: %d"%resp)
        else:
            raise MuxError("Invalid packet type received: %d"%resp)
    def _exchange(self, req, payload={}):
        mytag = self.pkttag
        self.pkttag += 1
        self.proto.sendpacket(req, mytag, payload)
        recvtag, data = self._getreply()
        if recvtag != mytag:
            raise MuxError("Reply tag mismatch: expected %d, got %d"%(mytag, recvtag))
        return data['Number']

    def listen(self):
        ret = self._exchange(self.proto.TYPE_LISTEN)
        if ret != 0:
            raise MuxError("Listen failed: error %d"%ret)
    def process(self, timeout=None):
        if self.proto.connected:
            raise MuxError("Socket is connected, cannot process listener events")
        rlo, wlo, xlo = select.select([self.socket.sock], [], [self.socket.sock], timeout)
        if xlo:
            self.socket.sock.close()
            raise MuxError("Exception in listener socket")
        if rlo:
            self._processpacket()
    def connect(self, device, port):
        ret = self._exchange(self.proto.TYPE_CONNECT, {'DeviceID':device.devid, 'PortNumber':((port<<8) & 0xFF00) | (port>>8)})
        if ret != 0:
            raise MuxError("Connect failed: error %d"%ret)
        self.proto.connected = True
        return self.socket.sock
    def close(self):
        self.socket.sock.close()

class USBMux(object):
    def __init__(self, socketpath=None):
        if socketpath is None:
            if sys.platform == 'darwin':
                socketpath = "/var/run/usbmuxd"
            else:
                socketpath = "/var/run/usbmuxd"
        self.socketpath = socketpath
        self.listener = MuxConnection(socketpath, BinaryProtocol)
        try:
            self.listener.listen()
            self.version = 0
            self.protoclass = BinaryProtocol
        except MuxVersionError:
            self.listener = MuxConnection(socketpath, PlistProtocol)
            self.listener.listen()
            self.protoclass = PlistProtocol
            self.version = 1
        self.devices = self.listener.devices
    def process(self, timeout=None):
        self.listener.process(timeout)
    def connect(self, device, port):
        connector = MuxConnection(self.socketpath, self.protoclass)
        return connector.connect(device, port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mux = USBMux()
    print("Waiting for devices...")
    if not mux.devices:
        mux.process(0.1)
    while True:
        print("Devices:")
        for dev in mux.devices:
            print(dev)
        mux.process()
```

I ran the above code in Python 3.7 and got the error.
The details of the error are as follows.

```
  File "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\usbmux.py", line 81, in sendpacket
    data = struct.pack("IIII", length, self.VERSION, req, tag) + payload
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

How can I rewrite this code to get rid of the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do/don’t you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) returns bytes in python 3, not a string as it did in python 2. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269501/10682164) answer to see one way to emulate the python 2 behavior.

**Edit**: actually you may need to do something slightly different, since it looks like [socket.send](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) wants bytes as input. So you'd need to convert the combined payload to bytes.

You could try changing the following code that seems to be populating the payload to return bytes in both cases. Notice the "b" added in the return values to specify bytes instead of str. You are hitting the TYPE_LISTEN case but should test the other case as well, as it looks like it had the same bug trying to concat str and bytes:

```
    def _pack(self, req, payload):
        if req == self.TYPE_CONNECT:
            return struct.pack("IH", payload['DeviceID'], payload['PortNumber']) + b"\x00\x00"
        elif req == self.TYPE_LISTEN:
            return b""
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid outgoing request type %d"%req)
```

You'll likely need to edit _pack in PlistProtocol as well.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
data = struct.pack("IIII", length, self.VERSION, req, tag) + payload
```

is causing the trouble. According to the struct.pack() docs, the method returns `bytes`.  You need to convert your `payload` also into `bytes` so that the two can be concatenated, making the error go away.

Not sure what your `payload` is, but encoding the payload using something like 'utf-8' might do the trick. I believe a simple `payload.encode()` will work, since 'utf-8' is the default encoding.  So, try:

```
data = struct.pack("IIII", length, self.VERSION, req, tag) + payload.encode()
#                                                          add this ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The error disappeared in this way!